# App file size differences in Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, app-store, google-play

Working with both app distributions services (android market and Apple App store) I have discovered a mystery.

The file size of an app is in general larger for an Apple app than for a Android app.
I can't seem to find any explanation for the differences, and it seems to be an untouched subject.

I have tried allot of different apps and the difference seems to vary between a couple of MB to 6-8 MB. So the question is, how come the file size is larger for Apple apps? What is the extra MB used for?

Examples:

## BBC:

Android: 918K - https://market.android.com/details?id=bbc.mobile.news.ww

Apple: 6.7 MB - http://itunes.apple.com/dk/app/bbc-news/id364147881?mt=8

***Due to some spam prevention, I'm unable to link directly to the rest.***

## British Airways

Android: 1.2 MB

Apple: 7.9 MB

## Northern Bank

Android: 2.1 MB

Apple: 6.4 MB

## Bank of America

Android: 727K

Apple: 2.1 MB

I could go on... If anyone can provide a statistics of file size for the two app distributions, confirming or disproving my theory. - I would appreciate it allot.

Comment: Researching the question I found that even the more basic graphics (buttons, panels, ect.) in all the supported resolutions, was placed in the Apple apps that I have had opportunity to examine. If this is normal procedure for Apple app development, then that can account for some of the extra MB. Is this normal for Apple apps?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I have just spent the last day or so trying to track this exact problem down. I have built a little game called BlockIT for Android, and now I have a running version for iOS. The extremely odd thing is that the Android version is 8.2 MB and the iOS version is 14.1 MB.

Now, since I am the owner of the source, I wanted to track this down and find out why. As many suggest here that it is the graphical elements - this is not the case. The entire data set (non code) was almost identical in each package. Which makes sense since I am using the same graphics in each application.

So, why is the code build so much different! My iOS code build was nearly 7 MB and the Android one was less than 3 MB. The code itself was written to run identically and all but small portions of code are exactly the same on each platform. What I found was that the build (iOS gcc) settings had massive effects on what size of output you get. If you set only to target ARM6 or ARM7 then the size of my code binary dropped from 7 MB to 5 MB. This indicates there are almost complete duplicates of functions and libraries for each target in the one binary! Additionally, the built-in debugging symbols dont seem to get entirely stripped. Finally, the encryption of the code also costs large amounts. This is probably the most puzzling, since Android signs their apk's in a similar fashion. It seems that the iOS signing is done very oddly.

So, I hope that helps. To reiterate:
- Images / Data don't seem to be the problem
- Code building on iOS generates multiple platform output in the one binary == lots of extra code (btw I dont wee why Apple does this - seems odd).
- Code encryption is not very size friendly on iOS.

There's no real way to fix the actual problem (again, odd and disappointing).

Comment: to give you some clarification about why it produces multiple output for different ARM versions: It's because different processor generations support additional functions directly by the processor to speed up code execution. But since these can only be executed on the correct architecture, you ofc also need code for when the device does not support certain instructions.
So why does apple do it? to improve performance on capable devices in exchange for some rather irrelevant file size difference.

Comment: Yes, I understand to meet different target platforms, but its odd because rather than solve it in an API or some sensible architecture, they include two complete copies of the libraries (its why they are roughly 2x). Hence. Odd. :)

Answer (score 6):

The binary executable in an iOS app is encrypted, and thus compresses very poorly or not at all.  The binary executable in an iOS app is compiled with some library code statically linked, which can often make it larger than interpreted Dalvik byte code for similar stuff.  iPhone apps tend to contain more high quality graphics content and artwork for multiple screen resolutions including the relatively large iPad display.

Comment: That makes sens. Android supports different resolutions, using a special folder structure. This makes Android able to automatically select the optimal graphics for the different resolutions. - Is this not a widely used solution?

Answer (score 1):

For a universal app in iPhone we need to put three size of images -

one for 320x480 px
second for 640x940 px (retina)
third for 768x1024 (iPad)

where as while developing a android application we need to put three kind of images -

hdpi (high)
mdpi (medium)
ldpi (low)

one more thing here in android there is no compulsory rule to put all three kind of images. Basically it depends on for which target you are making app , only for those resolution we need to put images.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, Apple Developers are using more full-screen size Images (in low def and Retina), and much more images than Android, and UI definitions files for iPhone (.XIB) are much bigger than XML files used in Android. There also should be a difference of Compression in packaging (.APK) is so hugely compressed ! And Finally maybe a difference in Including frameworks, but on this point I have no clue :)

Comment: Can it be that iOS apps are more statically linked to libraries whereas android the libraries are not included in the package?

Comment: You say that the .apk file i compressed, implying that Apple does not?

Comment: I guess it is, I don't think Apple would let uncompressed App on their store, especially after billions of downloads. For the libraries, I Have no idea; but still sounds weird why would Apple includes libraries in their packages