# Why ipa size is bigger than apk?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, apk, ipa

I am developing the Hybrid mobile apps for Android and Apple.

APP size is around 5MB for Android but ipa takes almost the double size 11.4MB. I am building the .ipa from xcode .

Is this something expected ?

Comment: Well found the similar issue here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354977/app-file-size-differences-in-android-and-ios)

Comment: are you using splash images? how many do you have for iOS? and for android?

Comment: I have tested without splash screen too but still the size higher than .apk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In iPhone applications (.ipa) the virtual machine is bundled inside your application. In android applications (.apk) that is not a case.

Comment: is there any valid reference for these?